# How can I disable all the Windows crash handlers like DrWatson and so on 

Tags: crash, crash-dumps, crash-reports, drwatson

I'm developing a unit test automatic execution application and I need that when one application crashes no dialog appears. A crash dump would be great but the main requirement is that no dialog is shown because I'm automating the execution and I won't automate those dialog.

I've disable the windows error reporting but the only change has been a different dialog without the send option.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember `WinDbg` has a way to be launched on crash, saving a minidump and exiting without any dialog.

Comment: Mmmm, what I would love is to find a way using only Windows.

Comment: Well, at least you might consider this program from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, but as I'm creating machines for integration tests I would like to have the least software the better. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I finally ended using this solution long time ago. Thanks!